# Android Application crashes when I use "android:layout_margin"

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my XML.

http://pastebin.com/vaw7xY7t

It works if I delete the line 18.

```
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
```

But if I add the

```
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
```

the program crashes on start and gives a message "Unfortunately ... has stopped working"

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare logcat throws up lots of errors, dunno which one to watch

Comment: You should be able to find a stack trace. In Eclipse you can add filter to your logcat to only include information from your appliation.

Comment: isn't layout_margin part of a view group? and thus not valid in a textview

Comment: @dmaij If I don't add that property, Textview doesn't fill up the entire 100% width. After adding margin property, the 'Graphical Layout' shows proper output. But when I run the app it crashes.

Comment: Don't trust the graphical layout, trust the compiler instead.

Comment: @dmaij the compiler doesn't throw up any errors, when I proceed to run it. The emulator says 'unfortunately app has stopped'

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: Don't trust the graphical layout, trust the layoutInflator. What I meant to say, and this is going to be completely offtopic, is that the graphical layout is there for convinience and does not use the same codebase as the inflator. When the inflator crashes, your graphical layout may look just fine. So, again, don't trust your graphical layout.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the layout_height of specify. Add this parameter to wrap_content.
Perhaps ?

Comment: Add layout height and layout width. i am pretty sure a view needs to have these two values as a bare mimimum else how large or small should the system draw your UI component?

Comment: Not on the first textView from the pastebin link.

You should also paste the xml file here instead of pasteBin

Answer (score -1):

The real reason for the crash was because I was using a string resource to store dimension.
If you are storing a dimension, '10dp' in a string, use 'dimen' instead:
Instead of referencing it like @string/blah, use @dimen/blah.

Check out this answer:

[android eclipse using string resource for text size in layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146057/android-eclipse-using-string-resource-for-text-size-in-layouts)